# laravel custom validation error for each regex pattern

Tags: php, regex, validation, laravel-7

so I have validated a password with different regex pattern, now I want to return different validation messages for each pattern so that user can get a exact error message, I don't want to return one message for all patterns.

so whatever I've tried so far is as below

```
        $request->validate([
            'password'=>[
                'required',
                'min:8',
                'string',
                'regex:/[a-z]/',
                'regex:/[A-Z]/',
                'regex:/[0-9]/',
                'regex:/[@$!%*#?&]/', //required special chars
                'not_regex:/^(20|19|0)/', //must not start with 20 or 19 or 0
                'not_regex:/(.)\1{1}/', //doubles are not allowed
                'not_regex:/(123(?:4(?:5(?:6(?:7(?:89?)?)?)?)?)?|234(?:5(?:6(?:7(?:89?)?)?)?)?|345(?:6(?:7(?:89?)?)?)?|456(?:7(?:89?)?)?|567(?:89?)?|6789?|789)/', //sequential number must not be more than 2
            ]
        ],[
            'password.regex.0'=>'password must contain a lower case character',
            'password.regex.1'=>'password must contain an upper case character',
        ]);
```

but the custom message is not working for regex patterns, its only returning common message "The password format is invalid." is there any ideal way to do that?

> NB: I have checked all the stack overflow questions but got no
> solutions, My validation works fine just need to return specific error
> message for each pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create either a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) for each regex with an appropriate message in each, or you could use an [inline closure](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#using-closures).

```php
$request->validate([
            'password'=>[
                'required',
                'min:8',
                'string',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    if (!preg_match(“/[@$!%*#?&]/“, $value)) {
                        $fail('You must include a special character.');
                    }
                },
                // ...
            ]
        ],[
            'password.regex.0'=>'password must contain a lower case character',
            'password.regex.1'=>'password must contain an upper case character',
        ]);
```

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm, but I had to wrap the pattern with string like `!preg_match("/[@$!%*#?&]/", $value)`, I think you should add it to avoid syntax errors